# Container fix width. Center div dynamic width. want left right divs to fill out remaining width equally

Tags: css, html, dynamic, autofill

Have Three columns..Combine width of all three is fixed.. 2nd ( center ) column will have dynamic content.. I need left and right column to fill out remaining space ( container width - center column dynamic width )equally.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/htKje/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="bg"></div>
   <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
   <div class="bg"></div>
</div>

CSS :
.container { width:500px; }
.bg {backgrould:#CCC; }
```

Comment: Do you need to have content in left and right columns, or are they just for setting the background?

Comment: @Ana just background as per my design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the left and right columns just for setting the background, then most probably, you don't even need them at all.

Simply setting the `background` on the `.container`, giving the same container `text-align: center`, making the center column `inline-block` and reseting the `background` and `text-align` on it will do the trick.

[**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3742502)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='c'>booooo add remove text here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
.c {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
}
```