# Three column div with fixed width for the center div and left and right sharing the rest of the space equally

Tags: css

```
<div id="IWillShareTheRemainingWidthWithTheRightOne">left stuff</div>
<div id="IAmAFixedWidth">center stuff </div>
<div id="IWillShareTheRemainingWidthWithTheLeftOne">right stuff</div>
```

The left and right would take up all the available rest of the space

Someone else [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474212/container-fix-width-center-div-dynamic-width-want-left-right-divs-to-fill-out) has asked this question and the solution proposed worked for him because he just needed to set background on the left and right. In my case I do have to put some content on the left and right div.

I have also seen solutions where left is fixed and right one takes rest of the space. I even found some solutions around left and right having fixed width and center taking remaining.

But I haven't found exactly what I need.

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle with the code you have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DugGC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at [this place](http://pmob.co.uk/temp/3col-centrefixed2.htm)
Someone called Paul who had done it years ago blogged about it [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?442731-Impossible-CSS-layout-3-Columns-Fixed-center-Fluid-left-right)

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DugGC/7/)

```
<div id="IWillShareTheRemainingWidthWithTheRightOne">stuff on left</div>
<div id="IAmAFixedWidth">stuff on center</div>
<div id="IWillShareTheRemainingWidthWithTheLeftOne"> 
    <div id="insideOf3rd">    
        stuff on right
    </div>
</div>


#IAmAFixedWidth {
    width:100px;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block
}

#IWillShareTheRemainingWidthWithTheRightOne {
width:50%;
margin-right:-50px;
background:magenta;
float:left;
}

#IWillShareTheRemainingWidthWithTheLeftOne {
width:50%;
margin-left:-60px;
background:magenta;
float:right;
}

#insideOf3rd {
margin-left:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs an inline-block css.

```
div{display:inline-block;}
#IAmAFixedWidth {
    width:100px;
    background:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DugGC/5/

**Edit:**
Try this:

```
    div{display:table-cell; background: orange; }
    #content{width:550px; background: black; display: table}
    #IAmAFixedWidth {
        width:100px;
        background:green;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DugGC/6/

Comment: Sorry, another requirement for me was that the left and right would take up all the available rest of the space. I might not have been so clear and I apologize for that. With this implementation, the left and right would only take the space that they need. I am setting the status to unanswered as I really need some help to get this right.

Comment: Now I added a container div with display:table, each children div is display:table-cell, in this new fiddle It works.  http://jsfiddle.net/DugGC/6/

Comment: I give you some points for providing another way, but using table layout is in general not recommended. But I was able to find something on google. Take a look at http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/3col-centrefixed2.htm